# FireStoreのデータを取得しながらViewの遷移をしたい

Tags: firebase, swiftui

下記のようなデータ構成でFirestoreにデータが格納してあり、
下記のような遷移を実現したいです。
感覚的にはよく使いそうな遷移だと思うのですが、どのように実現するのが良いのか分からず、
どなたかにご教示いただきたいです。

【データの構成】
Collection("Theme")→document（）→各documentにCollection("Photo")が含まれる

【実現したいViewの遷移】
Themeの情報が含まれたView→そのThemeのPhotoが表示されるView

```
//Themeの情報が含まれたView
import SwiftUI

struct ThemeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var themeList = ThemeObserver()

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            List(themeList.status){ theme in
                NavigationLink(destination: PhotoView(theme: self.theme)){
                ThemeView(oneTheme: theme)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//UserのPhotoが表示されるView
struct PhotoView: View {
    var theme : ThemeEntity
    var ObservedObject var photoList = PhotoObserver()
    var body: some View {
        photoList.pickup(theme: theme)

        return ScrollView{//ScrollViewを外すとなぜか表示されるようになる
            VStack{
                ForEach(self.status,id: \.self){photo in
                    Text(photo.title)//例
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//FireStoreからThemeを取得するObservableObject
class ThemeObserver:ObservableObject {
    @Published var status = [ThemeEntity]()

        init() {
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
            db.collection("Theme").addSnapshotListener{(snap, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("\(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                }
                for i in snap!.documentChanges {
                        let id = i.document.documentID
                        let themeImageURL = i.document.get("themeImageURL") as? String ?? ""
                        ...

                        self.status.append(ThemeEntity(id: id, themeImageURL: themeImageURL, ...))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



//FIreStoreからfuncでPhotoを取得するObservableObject
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import SwiftUI

class PhotoObserver: ObservableObject{
    @Published var status = [PhotoEntity]()

    func pickup(theme: ThemeEntity) {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        db.collection("Theme").document("\(oneTheme.id)").collection("Photos").addSnapshotListener{(snap, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("\(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
            }

            var tempStatus: [PhotoEntity] = []

            for i in snap!.documentChanges {
                    let id = i.document.documentID
                    let title = i.document.get("title") as? String ?? ""
                    ....

                    tempStatus.append(PhotoEntity(id: id, title: title,...))
            }
            self.status = tempStatus
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

まず第一に、SwiftUIを使う場合の大前提として、Viewの`body`の定義の中に直接「処理」を書いてはいけません。なんらかの処理をクロージャーとして受け取るイニシャライザやメソッドを呼んで、`photoList.pickup(theme: theme)`のような「処理」は、そのクロージャーの中に記述します。

今回のように画面遷移時に処理を実行させたいのであれば、[`onAppear`メソッド](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/3276931-onappear)が適当でしょう。

```
struct PhotoView: View {
    var theme : ThemeEntity
    @ObservedObject var photoList = PhotoObserver()

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(self.photoList.status, id: \.self) {photo in
                    Text(photo.title)
                }
            }
        }.onAppear {
            self.photoList.pickup(theme: self.theme)
        }
    }
}
```

(ご質問中のコードで、`struct PhotoView`の定義中にある、`var ObservedObject var photoList = ...`の部分は、`@ObservedObject var photoList = ...`の間違いではないかと思うのですが?)

---

で、Firestoreからのデータの取得をダミーに置き換えてテストしたんですが、残念ながら初期表示がうまくいきませんでした。

どうも`ScrollView`には一部の状態変化があっても画面更新を行わない場合があるらしく、本家英語版のstackoverflowに、似たような状況での回避策がいくつか載っていました。
[SwiftUI ScrollView not getting updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58830896/6541007)

どの回避策も、いかにも「回避策」と言ったものなのですが、とりあえずアイデアだけ一番得票の多い回答から拝借して、以下のようなコードを書いたところ、こちらのダミーベースでは表示されるようになりました。

```
struct PhotoView: View {
    var theme : ThemeEntity
    @ObservedObject var photoList = PhotoObserver()

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: photoList.status.isEmpty) {
            VStack {
                ForEach(self.photoList.status, id: \.self) {photo in
                    Text(photo.title)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.photoList.pickup(theme: self.theme)
        }
    }
}
```

あなたの環境で確実に動くものかどうかなんとも言えませんが、お試しください。